# Laravel: br in @section

Tags: laravel

How can I make the 'Intelligence (AI)' as second line? Is it possible to do break line in @section for h1 title?

```
   @section('title','Artificial Intelligence (AI)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this for multiline

```php
@section('title')

Artificial Intelligence
<br>
(AI)

@endsection
```

Comment: If you want to show the section immediately you can also use `@show` instead of `@endsection`

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul, this solved my problem. I forgot that we can do multiline for @section.‍♀️Still not familiar with Laravel, but will keep learning in future. Thank you for your helps. :D

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos for your extra answers. Learnt new things from you :D

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the HTML is being escaped you can try and use the HTML helper class:

```
@section('title', new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString('Artificial<br>Intelligence (AI)'))
```

which should show the string as unescaped HTML